# Temporarily disable touchstart event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mobile based web application. Currently I am encountering an issue when ajax calls are being made. The wait spinner which is enclosed in a div can be clicked through on the ipad device. The javascript event being triggered is touchstart. Is there anyway to prevent this event from going through normal processing?

Tried to call the following, however it did not work.

```
Disable
 document.ontouchstart = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
Enable
  document.ontouchstart = function(e){ return true; }
```

How touchstart is handled

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function (eventObj) {
    //toggle for view-icon
    if (eventObj.target.id == "view-icon") {
        $("#view-dropdown").toggle();
    } else if ($(eventObj.target).hasClass("view-dropdown")) {
        $("#view-dropdown").show();
    } else {
        $("#view-dropdown").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Well where are you handling touchstart? The event shouldn't be causing any issues unless you have code that is running when the event fires.

Comment: I solved this by creating a flag, touchLocked. If it was true the .on would return false. If it was not true then it would go through the rest of the method.

Answer (score 1):

As user3032973 commented, you can use a touchLocked variable, which is working perfectly.

I have used it in combination with the Cordova Keyboard-Plugin. Scrolling will be disabled the time the keyboard is shown up and reenabled the time the keyboard is hiding:

```
var touchLocked = false;

Keyboard.onshowing = function () {
    touchLocked = true;
};

Keyboard.onhiding = function () {
    touchLocked = false;
};

document.ontouchstart = function(e){
    if(touchLocked){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```